# progress bar not showing before thread

Tags: android

i am trying to show a progress bar before a thread but it is not showing. My code looks like below:

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });



        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

        //doSomeStuff();

            }
        });
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you making a new Thread and then instantly calling `join()` on it? `join()` pauses the current Thread until the referenced Thread completes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you want to set progress you need to set current progress in progress bar

```
   progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressStatus = 0;
   // Start long running operation in a background thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    while (progressStatus < 100) {
                        progressStatus += 1;
                        // Update the progress bar and display the
                        //current value in the text view
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it gives me an error: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"